# KTable data - Bytes printing

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, ktable

I have a KTable in Kafka that when I debug I get the data in bytes.

If I want it in String, what should I do? I have attached an snippet as well.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The `key` of the LinkedHashMap is a string. If you expand *any String* in the debugger, you'll see its byte representation.

That highlighted "value" is not the value of the map's keys, that would be the value field in the bottom of the screenshot.

Plus, you're expanding the topology builder, which is not the actual values in the Table. If you want to see the data in the table, `table.toStream().print()`

Answer (score -1):

Something like:

```
    public static String byteArrayToHexString(byte[] rawBytes) {
        final String HEXCHARS = "0123456789abcdef";
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(rawBytes.length * 2);

        for (int i = 0; i < rawBytes.length; i++) {
            int ix = (rawBytes[i] >> 4) & 0xF;
            sb.append(HEXCHARS.charAt(ix));
            ix = rawBytes[i] & 0xF;
            sb.append(HEXCHARS.charAt(ix));
        }

        return sb.toString();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am guessing I can convert it Materialized view itself. Are you aware of that?

Comment: I'm not sorry. Just thought I'd post a generic solution